# Dúvida sobre inserção de conteúdo de um arquivo .txt para uma lista

Tags: python-3.x

Estou com uma dúvida sobre inserção do conteúdo de um arquivo de texto para uma lista em python.

Eu quero colocar a primeira linha de um arquivo de texto numa lista. No meu código ele executa a tarefa mas aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> ```
> [<_io.TextIOWrapper name='lista2.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>].
> ```

Abaixo segue o meu código:

```
print ("-"*50)
print ("-"*50)

itens = []
item=1
arquivo = open('lista.txt','w')

with open ('lista.txt') as f1:
    conteudo = f1.read()

with open ('lista2.txt','w') as f2:
    f2.write(conteudo[::-1])
    itens.append(f2)

print (itens)

print ("-"*50)
print ("-"*50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método ***open*** abre o arquivo e retorna um TextIOWrapperobjeto, mas não lê o conteúdo dos arquivos.

Para realmente obter o conteúdo do arquivo, você precisa chamar o método ***read*** nesse objeto, assim:

```
G = open(P, 'r')
print(G.read())
```

No entanto, você deve cuidar de fechar o arquivo chamando o método ***close*** no objeto de arquivo ou usando como vc fez usand:o *with open(...)*, usando sintaxe que garantirá que o arquivo seja fechado corretamente, da seguinte maneira:

```
with open(P, 'r') as G:
    print(G.read())
```

Então vc não precisa usar o este comando antes:
***arquivo = open('lista.txt','w')***

```
print ("-"*50)
print ("-"*50)

itens = []
item=1

with open ('lista.txt') as f1:
    conteudo = f1.read()

with open ('lista2.txt','w') as f2:
    f2.write(conteudo[::-1])
    itens.append(f2)


print ("-"*50)
print ("-"*50)
```

Desta foram no arquivo lista2.txt fica invertido o elementos do lista.txt

Answer (score 0):

Focando diretamente o que foi perguntado, acontece que o que é escrito na lista é o objeto que representa o acesso ao arquivo, o `f2`:

```
with open ('lista2.txt','w') as f2:
    f2.write(conteudo[::-1])
    itens.append(f2) # <-- aqui escreve f2 e não o conteudo
```

E esse objeto é na verdade um `TextIOWrapper` como vê na saída apresentada. Para além disso está a escrever no arquivo o conteúdo invertido através de *slicing* com o `[::-1]`.

No entanto você começa por abrir o arquivo que pretende ler como escrita, com `w`, e isso acaba por limpar todo o conteúdo dele de imediato, nesta linha:

```
arquivo = open('lista.txt','w') # ao abrir inicialmente como 'w' limpa o conteudo
```

Essa linha deve ser removida de todo.

Depois o `read` lê o arquivo todo, mas se pretende apenas a primeira linha, deve utilizar o [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) que é mais direto e simples.

Então o código que tem pode ser reescrito assim:

```
print ("-"*50)
print ("-"*50)

with open ('lista.txt', 'r') as f1:
    conteudo = f1.readline()

itens = []    
with open ('lista2.txt','w') as f2:
    f2.write(conteudo)
    itens.append(conteudo)

print (itens)
print ("-"*50)
print ("-"*50)
```

Comment: Obrigado.  Me ajudou muito. Valeu.